# Using special characters ($, % etc.) in PythonTeX

Tags: pythontex

I am writing a LaTeX document that retrieves values from defined ranges in a spreadsheet.

I have a Python function that I know works (it works in VS Code).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
import openpyxl
file = 'myfile.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, data_only = True)

def excelValue(definedName):
    address = list(wb.defined_names[definedName].destinations

    for sheetname, cellAddress in address:
        cellAddress = cellAddress.replace('$', '')
    worksheet = wb[sheetname]
    return worksheet[cellAddress].value
\end{pycode}
```

The issue is in the line `cellAddress.replace('$', ' ')`, where LaTeX doesn't like the `$` symbol.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about your Python code and about the formatting of the material you need to retrieve from a spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome. I think you are missing a parenthessis in `adress` definition. PythonTeX `pycode` does only print its contents verbatim into TeX output routine, so there should be no problem with `$` sign. What error message did you got from TeX or PythonTeX?

Comment: There were two things missing:
The parenthesis in the address definition, and the PATH that TexMaker was using wasn't properly set up, so it didn't recognise the import openpyxl command.